# Xcode Build Error Prefix.pch Defines.h file not found

Tags: xcode, build

I work on Unity3d v2017.4.301f, on win10.
I build Xcode project on pc, then transfer to Mac and build with Xcode.

I have an app that previously built fine in Xcode.
On a recent export from Unity3d to Xcode, I am getting the build error shown below:

> Defines.h file not found

It is inside the file Prefix.pch in the Classes folder.
It is nested inside

```
IF USING OBJC
     Include "Defines.h"
```

I have never seen this error, and cannot find anyone who has a discussion on this.

Other times I have seen file not found was from missing frameworks.
I am not missing any frameworks that I am aware of, and there is no ObjectiveC framework for me to add ( never needed it before either).

Please assist if you are familiar with the root of this file not found issue.

Comment: Solved: In Unity 3D, I changed the iOS architecture to Universal, and it has resolved my build error.

Comment: I have same problem :(